# Screenchange Event

Tags: python, c, windows

Is there a way to know whether the screen has been changed or not ?

Comment: What do you mean by "screen has been changed"? And what do you want to do with this event, should it exist?

Comment: Yep. Cause at the moment I am developing an RDP App from the scratch. and I dont want to send the screenshots in an interval. rather I'll send it on screen change event.

Comment: Does your screen include the system clock?

Comment: Hmm +1 Nice Question. Well It doesn't Matter. If its possible without System Clock then even The solution is Welcome

Comment: RDP App in Python? Not much chance of success there. Most modern RDP apps use mirror drivers I believe. Does the world need another RDP app? Do you really believe you can do better than VNC or RDP?

Comment: Yes I need to make an RDP app as a part of My Propitiatory app. If its hard to do in Python I'll do in in C++

Comment: @Neel I'm not sure, but my instincts tell me that Python is not the right choice here.

Comment: Ya I am also thinking that But still is there a way to get the screen change event in C ???? I've no problem to switch back to C

Comment: @Neel As far as I know there is no screen change event. Even if there was, I think you'll find there's more to it than that. By the way, did you know that VNC is GPL?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should possible by setting a [GetMsgProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) hook in order to detect every WM_PAINT event.

The hook should just change a flag in a shared memory read by the main RDP process.